# How can I combine annotation based RequestMapping with static content?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-web

I have some content that needs dynamic loading in my Controller and some content that I want to deliver in a static manner.

Currently I have to configure the path of the controller manually in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, e.G. the `@RequestMapping` isn't working. If I remove the `<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />` line from my `dispatcher-servlet.xml` the annotation is properly read again.

I've tried to change the context url for dispatcher servlet in `web.xml` and place the static pages outside of springs control, but that didn't work either, so I reverted it.

My goal is to remove the `urlMapping` bean from `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and have that done by the annotations. As far as I understood that should also get rid of the `AbstractController` and the `handleRequestInternal` parts.

What confuses me is that I can use only the annotations when I leave out the static resources line.

Here are the relevant exerts of my current state:

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.pkg.containing.controllers" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
  p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
  p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
    <props>
      <prop key="/dashboard/*">dashboardController</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller in package:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dashboard")
public class DashboardController extends AbstractController {
  public ModelAndView getSite() {
    ModelAndView retVal = new ModelAndView("dashboard_base");
    retVal.addObject("url", "/dashboard");
    return retVal;
  }
  @Override
  protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    return getSite();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must tell the mvc part of spring that it should honor your annotations as well. So if you add this line to your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` it will work:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```